# Android OBD command response not coming in Hexadecimal

Tags: android, obd-ii

I am using the distance command(0131\r) to get the Obd response from Car.
But the response I am getting for distance command is like:
N10DO DATA,
0PS0DDP,
0O0S,
ADE,
These are not in Hexadecimal. So how can i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to recognize the response by regular expression.
regEx for valid response must be similar to

> [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}

or something like that. So the java code will be:

> response.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\r?" );

Match function returns boolean.

regEx for invalid response will contain WORDS recognition patterns.
Now I'am working on OBD connector tool too, so I will provide more code when it will be tested properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like multiple responses are coming interweaved. Please check your receiving buffer / code.